# How to show a SharePoint calendar view in a WebPart?

Tags: server

I have a SharePoint calendar and i want to show it in SharePoint calendar view in my webpart but i have no idea how to do this (I may apply some programming to it before showing). I have googled it and found that the following links maybe useful for showing in a page.

[Calendar View not properly displaying in WebPart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101580/calendar-view-not-properly-displaying-in-webpart)

http://cameron-verhelst.be/blog/2013/03/24/sharepoint-2010-calendar-view-on-xsltlistviewwebpart/

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSSharePointCustomCalendar-0e922479

Could any one tell me is it possible to show a Calendar view in a webPart?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does the SPCalendarView  possible solution?

Comment: As I understood, you want to show calendar in a web part on certain page?

Comment: @DaniloKorac yes. And it should be able to configurable for the event source of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Create web part page in your site pages library.
[image]

step 2: In **Parts** section, choose your calendar list and click on add button in lower right corner.
[image]

And that is it. Now you can customize your web part with calendar list.
You will find [here](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/sharepoint/how-to-edit-web-part-properties-in-sharepoint-2013/) about how to edit web part properties. Example, change title of web part or dimensions of it.

**Edit:** To better see images, click on right mouse button View image so image can be presented in full scale.

Comment: X.X i am so sorry that i am asking how to show a custom Calendar View in program instead of build-in sharepoint list..

Comment: When you add calendar list to web part, (How to do it) I posted a link bellow images. Click to edit web part properties. After properties pop up, in List Views part in Selected View choose your custom view and click Apply, Ok and then Stop editing.

Comment: i have 127 site collection which should embed this webpart.. should i do the above stop 127 times? :(

Comment: I don't understand your last question. Your original question was how to embed calendar list to web part. If it is not your real question please do edit original question and write what you want.